# Formatting calculated fields in Django to have spaces as decimal thousand separator

Tags: python, django

I've come across a strange behaviour of Django formatting. Best described by an example:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   value= models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

my_template.html:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{calculated_sum|floatformat|intcomma}} # improperly formatted (commas instead of spaces)
{{some_qs.0.value|floatformat|intcomma}} #properly formatted (spaces instead of         
                                         #commas as thousand separator
```

View that uses the template to generate an HTML content for an email:

```
some_qs = MyModel.objects.all()
calculated_sum= legal_entity_own_instance.get_latest_orders_sum()
context = Context({'calculated_sum':calculated_sum, 'some_qs':some_qs})

html_content = render_to_string('my_template.html', context)
```

For some reason, `some_qs.0.value` is formatted as expected (with spaces instead of commas as a thousands separator). That is, 12345 renders as 12 345. But the strange think is that `calculated_sum` is formatted with commas (12345 is formatted as 12,345).

Definition of get_latest_orders_sum:

```
def get_latest_orders_sum(self):
        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(...).aggregate(Sum('value'))
        order_sum = qs['value__sum']
        return order_sum
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason of wrong formatting ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing `return order_sum` to `return int(order_sum)` or doing the logic to add a space in your get_latest_orders_sum func. ie

```
return str(order_sum).replace("," " ")
```

Comment: Well, I want to avoid replacing approach, since it doesn't seem a clean solution to me given the built-in django tools (meaning filters). As for explicit int conversion, it's actually decimal (as you can see from the model provided) - and I DO WANT it to be decimal. You could argue that the function returns a string (I had doubts on this). But I checked it - its decimal. And this what makes me confused. Two variables of the same type are passed to the template and one of them renders as expected, while the second one does not :(